# How to edit/update data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been researching everywhere regarding this matters and i still cant edit/update my entry. Noted, this is my first real program and my level is somewhat mediocre. So i would like to seek your advise/help regarding this matter.

CODE:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    $sql = "select * from hotels where BIL =" .$_GET['edit'];
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $hotel = $_POST['hotel'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $update = "update hotels set $hotel = 'hotel', $address = 'address' where BIL = ".$_GET['edit'];
    $up = mysqli_query($link, $update);
    if (isset($sql)){
        die ("Error $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else 
    {
        header ("location: view.php");
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" >
New Hotel: <br  />
<textarea name="hotel" cols="50" rows="2" value="<?php echo $row['hotel']; ?>" /></textarea>
<br />
Address: <br / >
<textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="10" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>" /></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
</form>

<script>
function update(){
    var x;
    if(confirm("update Succesfully") == true){
        x= "update";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Extra note**: I copied this code from a youtube channel...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQzRDwY6zPc
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That YouTube channel gave you bad code then, because they didn't use prepared statements.

Comment: Your statements are inverted and dangerous. `update TABLE set COLUMN = 'VALUE', COLUMN2 = 'value'...` You can use backticks to encapsulate the  columns, quotes are for strings.

Comment: Change first `<textarea name="address"` to `<textarea name="hotel"` you took same name for both.

Comment: @Niklesh ops sorry about that, then may i know the next step?

Comment: `first` means `first from two` no next step

Comment: @SyedShahrulShafiq Update your SQL to be valid, use error reporting, use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please, for your own safety **do not** use random YouTube tutorials. It's the blind leading the blind in most cases. If you're interested in doing [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) then have a look at the various
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) available and find one that fits your style and needs. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example of one that's easy to pick up, and the introduction lessons there will show you the *right* way to do this without all the confusion in most tutorials.